# Suddenly no In App Billing V3 Support anymore

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

Since 3 days my Samsung Galaxy Star, doesn't support In App Billing Version 3 anymore. I reinstalled Eclipse and downloaded the Android SDK an other whole time.

Did someone had ever the same problem?

It fails at:

```
public void startSetup(final OnIabSetupFinishedListener listener) {
    // If already set up, can't do it again.
    if (mSetupDone)
        throw new IllegalStateException("IAB helper is already set up.");



    // Connection to IAB service
    logDebug("Starting in-app billing setup.");
    mServiceConn = new ServiceConnection() {

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            logDebug("Billing service disconnected.");
            mService = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            logDebug("Billing service connected.");
            mService = IInAppBillingService.Stub.asInterface(service);
            String packageName = mContext.getPackageName();
            try {
                logDebug("Checking for in-app billing 3 support.");
***HERE IT SEEMS TO FAIL!!***  int response = mService.isBillingSupported(3, packageName, ITEM_TYPE_INAPP);
                if (response != BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_OK) {
                    if (listener != null) {
                        listener.onIabSetupFinished(new IabResult(response,
                                "Error checking for billing v3 support."));
                    }
                    return;
                }
                logDebug("In-app billing version 3 supported for " + packageName);
                mSetupDone = true;
            }
            catch (RemoteException e) {
                if (listener != null) {
                    listener.onIabSetupFinished(new IabResult(IABHELPER_REMOTE_EXCEPTION,
                            "RemoteException while setting up in-app billing."));
                }
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



            if (listener != null) {
                listener.onIabSetupFinished(new IabResult(BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_OK, "Setup successful."));
            }
        }
    };
    boolean attempt = mContext.bindService(new Intent("com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND"),
            mServiceConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

    if (!attempt) {
        Log.e(mDebugTag, "Failed to bind to Service with name com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND");
    }
}`
```

Comment: did you found out what was wrong?